# Reading a File on OS X via Java - Is my path correct?

Tags: java, macos, file-io

I am trying to do this

```
File file = new File("/Users/Jon/Downloads/mynewalbum/artist - title.mp3");
```

I don't think its correct though as the properties returned don't seem correct. Maybe I have got a backslash or something wrong?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific if you want a useful answer. What properties are you talking about? And why do you think they "don't seem correct"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [File.exists()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) to see whether the file exists. If the path is wrong, the file will not exist.

Comment: Thanks made me realise I was missing a directory in the path.